# AWS Lambda update DynamoDB item

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table called Wishlist, and an existing DynamoDB Item which I'm calling "monitor".

I am trying to write a Lambda function that updates the "monitor" item as follows:

- takes the user's login ID, appends @gmail.com to it, and writes it to a new email attribute
- writes a timestamp to the item

Here is my code:

```
console.log('Loading function');
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var db = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) 
{
     var username  = event.username;
     var email = event.username+"@gmail.com";
     console.log(username + "," + email);

     var tableName = "WishList";
     var item = {
           "username":username,
           "email":  email,     
     };

     var params = {
         TableName:tableName, 
         Item: item
     };

     console.log(params);
     db.putItem(params, function(err,data){
         if (err) console.log(err);
         else console.log(data);
     });
};
```

How do I read the existing "monitor" item so that I can update it with putItem?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: Primary partition key - Device (String) @MarkB

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you need to:

- get the existing item by its key using [getItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property)
- modify the returned item
- put the modified item using [putItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property)

Alternatively, you can simply use [updateItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property) which will edit an existing item's attributes, or add a new item to the table if it does not already exist.

You can see sample code [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html).